# Development environment for python scripts using docker

Tags: python, docker

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to accomplish the next scenario: 
1. Python and all necessary packages installed on a docker container.
2. My code editor is running on my local machine.
3. When the script is changed, the container will re-run the script and give me the output. 
The point is that I don't want to rebuild the image and rerun the container after every change I'll make.
I just want to write the code "locally" and execute it as fast as possible in a container which running python.

Comment: I’d generally recommend non-Docker Python, a `requirements.txt` file to list your dependencies, and a virtual environment for this.  Why specifically do you want Docker?  What are you hoping to gain?

Comment: I'm just researching the capabilities of Docker and I wondered if such use case can be implemented

Answer (score 0):

A simple method:
1. Create a Dockerfile that `EXPOSE` the correct ports and installs the correct system and python packages
2. Specify the container command to be something like a `RUN sleep 3600` or `RUN tail -f /dev/null` to keep the container running
3. Run the Docker container with a **volume mount** to your code directory

You can edit your code with your local editor and run your tests with `docker exec`